# Issue with order function

Tags: r

I have this function and it takes a few parameters.
I have this part of the function here:

```
  sort.order <- order(inputs[,input.of.interest])
```

Iif I read inputs I get something like:

```
     Status Quo Vaccination
[1,]  10.409146   16.252537
[2,]   5.834875    9.373437
[3,]   5.784903   15.935623
[4,]  12.208484   18.654250
[5,]   9.786787   16.467321
[6,]   6.560276    9.689887
```

But what is input.of.interest supposed to be?
What does it mean, how is this function used?

Should it be a number, i.e if it's 2, what would it do?

Comment: It chooses the column to sort by.  If it's 1 it sorts by `Status Quo` and if it's 2 it sorts by `Vaccination`.

Comment: Great, please post this as an answer so i can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It chooses the column to sort by. If it's 1 it sorts by `Status Quo` and if it's 2 it sorts by `Vaccination`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- seq(20, 11, -1)
x
# [1] 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
order(x)
# [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
x[order(x)]
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Hope you see better how it works.